# Square brackets after class name in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, syntax

What does it means that the square brackets after class name SinglePermGroupPackagesUiInfoLiveData in Kotlin?

As I know it at present. If to new an instance to initialize the local variable packagesUiInfoLiveData, it should follows by parentheses and pass groupName as constructor parameter . The shorthand [key] syntax is supported by kotlin for retrieving a value from a map, but it should follow a variable rather than class name.

```
class CategorizedAppsLiveData(groupName: String)
        : MediatorLiveData<@kotlin.jvm.JvmSuppressWildcards
    Map<Category, List<Pair<String, UserHandle>>>>() {
        private val packagesUiInfoLiveData = SinglePermGroupPackagesUiInfoLiveData[groupName]
}
```

The definition of SinglePermGroupPackagesUiInfoLiveData from AOSP is as bellow:

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2019 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.android.permissioncontroller.permission.data

import android.app.Application
import android.os.UserHandle
import com.android.permissioncontroller.PermissionControllerApplication
import com.android.permissioncontroller.permission.model.livedatatypes.AppPermGroupUiInfo
import com.android.permissioncontroller.permission.utils.Utils

/**
 * LiveData for the UI info for all packages in a single permission group. Tracks which packages
 * have permissions in the given group, which should be shown on the UI, and which are granted or
 * not.
 *
 * @param app The current application
 * @param permGroupName The name of the permission group this LiveData represents
 */
class SinglePermGroupPackagesUiInfoLiveData private constructor(
    private val app: Application,
    private val permGroupName: String
) : SmartUpdateMediatorLiveData<Map<Pair<String, UserHandle>, AppPermGroupUiInfo>>() {

    private val permGroupLiveData = PermGroupLiveData[permGroupName]
    private val isCustomGroup = !Utils.getPlatformPermissionGroups().contains(permGroupName)
    private val permGroupPackagesLiveData = PermGroupsPackagesLiveData.get(
        customGroups = isCustomGroup)

    /**
     * Map<Pair<package name, UserHandle>, UI data LiveData>
     */
    private val appPermGroupLiveDatas = mutableMapOf<Pair<String, UserHandle>,
        AppPermGroupUiInfoLiveData>()

    /**
     * Map<Pair<packageName, userHandle>, UI data>.
     */
    private val shownPackages = mutableMapOf<Pair<String, UserHandle>, AppPermGroupUiInfo>()

    init {
        addSource(permGroupLiveData) { newPermGroup ->
            if (newPermGroup == null) {
                invalidateSingle(permGroupName)
                value = null
            }
        }

        addSource(permGroupPackagesLiveData) {
            updateIfActive()
        }
    }

    override fun onUpdate() {
        val thisPermGroupPackages = permGroupPackagesLiveData.value?.get(permGroupName)
        if (thisPermGroupPackages != null) {
            addAndRemoveAppPermGroupLiveDatas(thisPermGroupPackages.toList())

            if (thisPermGroupPackages.isEmpty()) {
                permGroupLiveData.value?.groupInfo?.let {
                    value = emptyMap()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun addAndRemoveAppPermGroupLiveDatas(pkgs: List<Pair<String, UserHandle>>) {
        val getLiveData = { key: Pair<String, UserHandle> ->
            AppPermGroupUiInfoLiveData[key.first, permGroupName, key.second]
        }

        setSourcesToDifference(pkgs, appPermGroupLiveDatas, getLiveData) { key ->
            val appPermGroupUiInfoLiveData = appPermGroupLiveDatas[key]
            val appPermGroupUiInfo = appPermGroupUiInfoLiveData?.value
            shownPackages.remove(key)

            if (appPermGroupUiInfo == null) {
                if (appPermGroupUiInfoLiveData != null &&
                    appPermGroupUiInfoLiveData.isInitialized) {
                    removeSource(appPermGroupUiInfoLiveData)
                    appPermGroupLiveDatas.remove(key)
                }
            } else {
                shownPackages[key] = appPermGroupUiInfo
            }

            if (appPermGroupLiveDatas.all { entry -> entry.value.isInitialized }) {
                permGroupLiveData.value?.groupInfo?.let {
                    value = shownPackages.toMap()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Repository for SinglePermGroupPackagesUiInfoLiveData objects.
     * <p> Key value is a string permission group name, value is its corresponding LiveData.
     */
    companion object : DataRepository<String,
        SinglePermGroupPackagesUiInfoLiveData>() {
        override fun newValue(key: String): SinglePermGroupPackagesUiInfoLiveData {
            return SinglePermGroupPackagesUiInfoLiveData(PermissionControllerApplication.get(),
                key)
        }
    }
}
```

/********************* Update ****************************/

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2019 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.android.permissioncontroller.permission.data

import android.app.ActivityManager
import android.content.ComponentCallbacks2
import android.content.res.Configuration
import androidx.annotation.GuardedBy
import androidx.annotation.MainThread
import com.android.permissioncontroller.PermissionControllerApplication
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

/**
 * A generalize data repository, which carries a component callback which trims its data in response
 * to memory pressure
 */
abstract class DataRepository<K, V : DataRepository.InactiveTimekeeper> : ComponentCallbacks2 {

    /**
     * Deadlines for removal based on memory pressure. Live Data objects which have been inactive
     * for longer than the deadline will be removed.
     */
    private val TIME_THRESHOLD_LAX_NANOS: Long = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.convert(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    private val TIME_THRESHOLD_TIGHT_NANOS: Long = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.convert(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    private val TIME_THRESHOLD_ALL_NANOS: Long = 0

    protected val lock = Any()
    @GuardedBy("lock")
    protected val data = mutableMapOf<K, V>()

    /**
     * Whether or not this data repository has been registered as a component callback yet
     */
    private var registered = false
    /**
     * Whether or not this device is a low-RAM device.
     */
    private var isLowMemoryDevice = PermissionControllerApplication.get().getSystemService(
        ActivityManager::class.java)?.isLowRamDevice ?: false

    init {
        PermissionControllerApplication.get().registerComponentCallbacks(this)
    }

    /**
     * Get a value from this repository, creating it if needed
     *
     * @param key The key associated with the desired Value
     *
     * @return The cached or newly created Value for the given Key
     */
    operator fun get(key: K): V {
        synchronized(lock) {
            return data.getOrPut(key) { newValue(key) }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Generate a new value type from the given data
     *
     * @param key Information about this value object, used to instantiate it
     *
     * @return The generated Value
     */
    @MainThread
    protected abstract fun newValue(key: K): V

    /**
     * Remove LiveData objects with no observer based on the severity of the memory pressure. If
     * this is a low RAM device, eject all caches always, including upon the UI closing.
     *
     * @param level The severity of the current memory pressure
     */
    override fun onTrimMemory(level: Int) {
        if (isLowMemoryDevice) {
            trimInactiveData(TIME_THRESHOLD_ALL_NANOS)
            return
        }

        trimInactiveData(threshold = when (level) {
            ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_BACKGROUND -> TIME_THRESHOLD_LAX_NANOS
            ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_MODERATE -> TIME_THRESHOLD_TIGHT_NANOS
            ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_COMPLETE -> TIME_THRESHOLD_ALL_NANOS
            ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_MODERATE -> TIME_THRESHOLD_LAX_NANOS
            ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_LOW -> TIME_THRESHOLD_TIGHT_NANOS
            ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_CRITICAL -> TIME_THRESHOLD_ALL_NANOS
            else -> return
        })
    }

    override fun onLowMemory() {
        onTrimMemory(ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_COMPLETE)
    }

    override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
        // Do nothing, but required to override by interface
    }

    fun invalidateSingle(key: K) {
        synchronized(lock) {
            data.remove(key)
        }
    }

    private fun trimInactiveData(threshold: Long) {
        synchronized(lock) {
            data.keys.toList().forEach { key ->
                if (data[key]?.timeInactive?.let { it >= threshold } == true) {
                    data.remove(key)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Interface which describes an object which can track how long it has been inactive, and if
     * it has any observers.
     */
    interface InactiveTimekeeper {

        /**
         * Long value representing the time this object went inactive, which is read only on the
         * main thread, so does not cause race conditions.
         */
        var timeWentInactive: Long?

        /**
         * Calculates the time since this object went inactive.
         *
         * @return The time since this object went inactive, or null if it is not inactive
         */
        val timeInactive: Long?
            get() {
                val time = timeWentInactive ?: return null
                return System.nanoTime() - time
            }
    }
}

/**
 * A DataRepository where all values are contingent on the existence of a package. Supports
 * invalidating all values tied to a package. Expects key to be a pair or triple, with the package
 * name as the first value of the key.
 */
abstract class DataRepositoryForPackage<K, V : DataRepository.InactiveTimekeeper>
    : DataRepository<K, V>() {

    /**
     * Invalidates every value with the packageName in the key.
     *
     * @param packageName The package to be invalidated
     */
    fun invalidateAllForPackage(packageName: String) {
        synchronized(lock) {
            for (key in data.keys.toSet()) {
                if (key is Pair<*, *> || key is Triple<*, *, *> && key.first == packageName) {
                    data.remove(key)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * A convenience to retrieve data from a repository with a composite key
 */
operator fun <K1, K2, V : DataRepository.InactiveTimekeeper> DataRepository<Pair<K1, K2>, V>.get(
    k1: K1,
    k2: K2
): V {
    return get(k1 to k2)
}

/**
 * A convenience to retrieve data from a repository with a composite key
 */
operator fun <K1, K2, K3, V : DataRepository.InactiveTimekeeper>
    DataRepository<Triple<K1, K2, K3>, V>.get(
        k1: K1,
        k2: K2,
        k3: K3
    ): V {
    return get(Triple(k1, k2, k3))
}
```

Comment: Square brackets would usually follow a variable or property name, but can also follow an object. Object instances can be accessed directly by name without a variable or property to reference them. This also goes for companion objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only that can be is an `operator get` https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#indexed defined on the class' companion object.
To know wheter that's the case here, I'd need to see the source of `DataRepository` which the companion object inherits from.

Comment: I have upload the source code of  `DataRepository`, I suppose you are correct, and I have understood more about how it works now. Thanks for you kindly explaination.